TypeaheadOnSelect events not firing in Angular in the context of an AG Grid editor
I'm writing a custom editor for an AG Grid in an Angular application using the ngx-bootstrap typeahead directive.
I have an input element with the typeahead directive, and I'm trying to handle the typeaheadOnSelect event to do something when an item is selected from the dropdown.
The dropdown gets poplulated correctly and I can select options, however the typeaheadOnSelect event is not being triggered when an option is selected.
Instead, the ag-grid getValue() method executes (and returns undefined as the selectedItem has not been set).
Here's the code for my input element:
<div class="dropdown">
        <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            [(ngModel)]="selectedItem"
            [typeahead]="getOptions()"
            (typeaheadOnSelect)="onSelect($event)"
            [typeaheadMinLength]="0"
            [typeaheadScrollable]="true"
            [typeaheadOptionsLimit]="100"
            typeaheadOptionField="showValue"
            container="body"
        />
    </div>

And here's the code for my onSelect:
public onSelect(event: TypeaheadMatch) {
        this.selectedItem = event.item;
    }

It seems like a straightforward pattern that should just "work" but I've been having no luck. Maybe I'm doing something daft? Or is there a known issue here?
Versions:

Angular 15
Ag Grid 13.3.1
ngx-bootstrap 10

